Node Modules MongoDb error when deploying NextJs project to Vercel
enter image description here
I am using mongodb with mongoose for my database and I am getting this error when i deploy my website to vercel. My website is running perfectly on localhost.
I cannot find this error anywhere on the internet.
I tried changing the node modules file but i cannot commit it so it doesn't makes a difference.

Here are the common causes and solutions to consider.
-- Environment Variable Mismatch
Verify MongoDB URI: Ensure your MongoDB connection URI in the code (process.env.MONGODB_URI) matches the actual URI for your deployed Vercel environment.
-- Missing or Incorrect Dependencies
Reinstall Dependencies: After making changes to your package.json, run npm install or yarn install in your project directory to ensure all required dependencies, including mongodb and mongoose, are installed correctly.
-- Version Compatibility Issues
Check Node.js Version: Vercel uses a specific Node.js version for deployment
-- MongoDB Connection Timeouts
Increase Timeout: If you're seeing connection timeouts, consider increasing the connection timeout in your MongoDB connection options. You can use the connectTimeoutMS option in MongoClient.connect()
-- Replica Set No Primary Error
MongoDB Configuration: This error might indicate an issue with your MongoDB replica set configuration. Double-check that your replica set has a primary node available during deployment.

My error is in the node modules file itself? Also, does it matter if i put mongodb uri in double quotes or no qoutes in .env file?
